# Git: How to create a new branch from a branch which is not current?

Tags: git, version-control

I have seen `git branch <newBranchName>` will create a new branch from the current branch. So for example if my current branch is `master` then `git branch build5` will create a new branch `build5` based on `master`.

But if my current branch is `master` and I have another branch `build3` and I want to create a new branch `build6` based on `build3`, how can I do that? Is it possible to do it without switching from my current branch `master`?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
git branch build6 build3
```

or

```
git checkout -b build6 build3
```

As you can see, `git branch` takes an optional parameter of a destination branch or commit from which to branch off of.